# How to surround Font Awesome plus sign with a box to make it look like a button?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
        <div id="menu-btn">
            <div><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i></div>
        </div>
```

I have this CSS:

```
.menu-btn {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    background-color: #A3D8D4;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

I am using w3 schools HTML and CSS tutorials.  If someone will kindly explain to me what I am doing wrong.  I am sorry for the beginner question and I hope please do not give the down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

for start, do attention to the type of tag you use , here you indicate a id but in your css you declare a class .
By changing it you should already have something that appears.

Comment: Thank you sir.  I am very ashamed of my mistake.